# How can I use decorators in a React Redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, decorator, redux

I’m creating simple application using React Redux. I want to use decorator to inject some methods in my component.. I saw similar code in other projects:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


@creatable
export default class BookDetails extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    if (!this.props.Activebook) {
      return <div> please select book</div>
    }
    return (
        <div>{this.props.Activebook.title}</div>
    );
  }
}


function creatable() {
  return Create => {
    @connect(state=>({Activebook : state.ActiveBook}))
   class MyDecorator extends Component {
     render() {
       console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
    console.log(this.props);
       console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
       return (
         <div>
           <Create
              {...this.props}
           />
         </div>
       )
     }

   }
    return MyDecorator;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the above code is not working. Why?

Comment: Define "not working"?

Comment: when I was testing this code it was showing me error near @ creatable
Just I want working example as above..

Comment: @user3126894 If you're getting an error, it should be provided in the description of the problem.

Comment: I have pushed code to repo
https://github.com/shivamitakari1990/react-book
can you please have look ??

Answer (score 13):

Please note that we do not recommend using decorators for connecting components.
You won’t find them anywhere in the official docs or examples.

Just because some community examples use them doesn’t mean it’s a good idea: the spec is still changing, the tooling support is flaky, and frankly, **you don’t need decorators for `connect()` because they desugar to simple function calls.**

For example, rather than

```
@connect(mapStateToProps)
class MyComponent extends Component {}
```

you should write

```
class MyComponent extends Component {}
MyComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

This way you won’t have to worry about them breaking until the proposal is part of the language.

I recommend you to stick to the conventions we use in the [official Redux examples](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Examples.html) and be very cautious about adopting experimental syntax extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Babel 6 doesn't support decorators with the `es2015` preset, nor with the `stage-0` preset. You'll have to add the `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` plugin to enable decorators:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
```

And add to your plugins in `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    ...
  ]
}
```

This is the easiest way I know of to get decorator support. They're not included in babel by default as they haven't actually been standardized yet.

Comment: oh!! that was missing in my package.json. let me give try with it. Thanks