# Missing context while using @connect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have `React` app which uses `react-redux` library. It works fine, I get my `store` context, I can dispatch actions. Beautiful.

Now I have met a problem. I want to declare child context in a root component and use it to pass global function right into the children.

```
export default class Root extends React.Component {
    globalFunc() {
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            globalFunc: this.globalFunc
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            { /* ChildComponent somewhere in here */ }
        );
    }
}

Root.childContextTypes = {
    globalFunc: PropTypes.func
}
```

The problem is inside one of the children I get empty object when I have `@connect` decorator from `react-redux`. When I remove the decorator, I get my context correctly. Why `Redux` removes the context? How to make a workaround?

```
@connect(mapStateToProps)
export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        console.log(this.context); // EMPTY {}
    }

    render() {
        // ...
    }
}

ChildComponent.contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.store.isRequired,
    globalFunc: PropTypes.func
}
```

Comment: What happens when you export after appending contextTypes? eg at the very end `export default ChildComponent;`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and when I used the "normal" HoC form for the `connect()` function instead of the decorator one, it was fixing the issue.
Note that this is not recommended to use the decorator form as said there by the creator of Redux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35642430/757461

Also if you really want to use decorators, I could fix this issue by defining my context using a decorator. Something similar to this:

```
export function context(contextTypes, context) {
  return DecoratedComponent => {
    return class extends Component {
      static childContextTypes = contextTypes;

      getChildContext() {
        return context(this.props)
      }

      render() {
        return <DecoratedComponent {...this.props} />
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
@context(contextTypes, getChildContext)
```